# What is this cracker called?

Tags: vocabulary, food

There is a kind of crackers that are similar to sliced bread. What are they called? They are sold by different brands and in a variety of flavours.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a food that you eat in your country.  What are they called in your language.  The chances are that, if a food is not native to an English speaking country, it won't have a specific English name, but will borrow the word from another language.

Comment: @JamesK nope, I don't know any word for that in any language.

Comment: Are they as hard as most crackers or do they retain some of the softness of bread? If they are hard and crisp they would appear to be almost inedible.

Comment: What did the source of the pictures call them in the language of the country where they coe from?

Answer (score 1):

In an answer, someone from the UK said he knows these types of crackers a "gourmet cracker" which seems to be valid to some point. I am not sure if this is just an adjective for marketing purposes or it actually is a name.

A related link http://www.hannahs-glutenfree.com/2015/04/the-foods-of-athenry-multiseed-gourmet.html